# data frame manipulation in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
id = c("A","B","C","A","C","C")
val = c(5,4,6,7,10,99)
df = data.frame(id, val)
df


id val   
 A   5
 B   4
 C   6
 A   7
 C  10
 C  99
```

Now I would like to re-arrange the `id` column (A, B, C...), keep their corresponding `val`, and then add a new column of `newid` starting with letter E, followed by three digits counting the number of `id` in the first column. The code is here:

```
id2 = c("A","A","B","C","C","C")
val2 = c(5,7,4,6,10,99)
newid = c("E001","E002","E001","E001","E002","E003")
df2 = data.frame(id2, val2, newid)
df2
```

and the final result is this:

```
id2 val2 newid
  A    5  E001
  A    7  E002
  B    4  E001   
  C    6  E001
  C   10  E002
  C   99  E003
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

dt[, newid := paste0('E', gsub(' ', '0', format(1:.N, width = 3))), keyby = id]
dt
#   id val newid
#1:  A   5  E001
#2:  A   7  E002
#3:  B   4  E001
#4:  C   6  E001
#5:  C  10  E002
#6:  C  99  E003
```

`keyby` here does the sorting, so no need to do it explicitly

Comment: thanks! one more question: do you know how can I concatenate the newid column with the id column? I want to get the id column sth like A:E001 A:E002 B:E001 C:E001 C:E002 C:E003. Thanks again!

Comment: use `paste0(id, ':E', gsub...)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do that, using the `order()` function to arrange the data, and the `sprintf()`, `sapply()` and `table()` functions to define `newid`.

```
df2 <- df[order(df$id, df$val), ]
df2$newid <- paste0("E", sprintf("%04d", unlist(sapply(table(df$id), function(x) 1:x))))
```